# Javascript: Create a new div in <body> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is going to be hard to explain but I will do my best. I want to write a Javascript function that takes two parameters (**title**, **content**) and creates a `<div>` tag in the `<body>` tag. The `<div>` tag should look like this.

```
<div>
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

My javascript code looks like this:

```
function addElement (title, content) {
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   var newH2 = document.createElement("h2");
   var title = document.createTextNode(header);
   newH2.appendChild(title);
   var p = document.createElement("p");
   var post = document.createTextNode(entry);
   p.appendChild(post);
   newDiv.appendChild(newH2);
   newDiv.appendChild(p);

   // Missing codes here...
}
```

I dont know how to finish my method. Because of I have almost hundreds of  tags inside my page and I want this new tags (when a user makes a new input) will appear on same place somewhere in the middle of the html code page in order to keep things organized.

Comment: Do you have any code samples of what you have tried already?

Comment: I tried to create a global variable for div id. `var divId = 1;` 
And then give a id to every new div. `newDiv.setAttribute(id, ++divId);` later on insert the newDiv to top of the previous div.
`var latestDiv = document.getElementById(divId - 1);`
`document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, latestDiv);`

Comment: “Appear on same place somewhere in the middle” does not describe what you want, and no context and no attempt at solving the placement problem is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use jQuery take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/panpymq2/

In my fiddle I am binding to a button press. Then I call a method that `appends` new generated html to the `body` of the page. You can enter change where you are appending the new HTML with CSS3 selectors. just modify the `$("insert selector there").append...`

**UPDATE**
As per the new requirements I have updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/panpymq2/1/

I now `prepend` the new html to the document.

Comment: Hello @Travis, can I use div id, like: `$("DIV-ID-HERE").append...` ?

Comment: @oxyt you can use any CCS selectors you choose. If you are selecting off a an id using somthing like: $("#what ever the id is") or a class: $(".class name"). Here is the an over view of the types of selectors that you can use: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/, http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: Thank you,  that was all I need to know :)

Comment: I get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined: func.js:7` which is `$("#addContent").on("click", function() {` I changed my button id attr. to `id="addContent"`... What am I missing here? Same problem with your updated fiddle.

Comment: @oxyt Have included jQuery in your source? If you haven't you can get it here: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Can you add the meat of the solution into your answer please?

Answer (score 2):

You already know how to add elements as children of other elements. That's what you used to add the `h2` and `p` to the `div`. You could use the same `appendChild` to add the `div` to the document:

```
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

But you don't want it at the bottom of the page--you want it "in the middle of the html code page". One straightforward way to do this is to add the `newDiv` to a container that's in the right place, in the middle of the page.

You'd first create this container in the page HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
  <p>stuff before</p>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <p>stuff after</p>
</body>
```

Then, finish off `addElement` with:

```
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(newDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be if addElement took a third parameter which is the sibling/parent you want to insert your new element next to/within.

```
function addElement(title, content, target) {
  ...
  target.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newDiv);
  // or
  target.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is as much of an HTML as a CSS problem. I've had the same issue.

One way of solving this problem is to make an (extra) container `<div>` as follows:

```
<div id="outer_container_elems">
     <div id="inner_container_elems">
           ...
     </div>
</div>
```

And append to `inner_container_elems`

Hope this helps!